# why this recursive function for size of binary tree gives stack overflow error?

Tags: java, tree

This code gives stack overflow error even for a tree with a single node.

```
int size(Node node)
    {
        if(root==null)
            return 0;
        return (1+size(root.left)+size(root.right));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're always using `root` in your function, it seems to be a attribute of the class, so you're calling the function on the same element again and again

```
int size(Node node){
    if(node==null){
        return 0;
    }
    return (1 + size(node.left) + size(node.right));
}
```

will solve ;)

---

And so you'll call the method like this : 
`int s = size(root);`